# Send/Receive data between a Flutter app and a desktop Java application

Tags: java, flutter, networking

I need to make a Mobile App that:

- Discover other Desktops on the same network;
- Connect with these Desktops and send data to them;
- It allows to be discovered by a Desktop application;
- Receive data from this Desktop application.

I need to do something like YouTube or Spotify where the available televisions are found, connect to one of them and send commands to it.

I understand that for that I need both a Mobile App and a client (that is running on the Desktop), but I am really at a loss as to what would be a basic implementation of this type of functionality with both Flutter for the Mobile part (if it is that it is possible to do this with Flutter) and with Java for the Desktop part (also if it is possible to do this with Java).

If it is not possible with Flutter/Java it can also be with another pair of Mobile/Desktop technologies that support Android, but the ideal is that it is even with Flutter/Java.

I appreciate any help, because with regard to that part of connectivity, network, wifi, p2p, etc., I don't have much knowledge.

Comment: Part of the problem is client-discovery, but another part (where I think your at) is client communication. So in the example you gave, the TVs must (A) be discoverable (B) The TVs and the devices need to be set up to connect to each other through a transport protocol (ssh, http, etc) and (C) both devices must have agreed on a communication/message convention (like HTML, XML, JSON... But it your example case it would be how the video is streamed & encoded)

Comment: Chromecasts (and similar) use MulticastDNS for discovery - there appears to be a Flutter package for this (no idea of it's quality). Java also provides a MulticastSocket class which may be of help